# Why can't I two-way bind array index to a model in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying to do what seems such a simple thing: I have an array of string values, which I want to bind to a `select`'s `option`s and bind the index of the selected value to a variable. But neither using `ng-options` nor regular `options` with `ng-repeat` seems to fully work. The latter works once you start selecting values, but does not bind to the value set at page load.

Here's a Codepen illustrating the issue. http://codepen.io/modo_lv/pen/xGYQjM (click on "View Compiled" to see pure HTML and JavaScript). Notice how both dropdowns are empty at first, even though the value they are bound to is already set. And selecting anything in the first dropdown causes the value to become unset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can' bind it because $index is not defined for `ngOptions`, it's only `ngRepeat` thing. If you want to know the index of the option you can calculate it with [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method:

```
<select ng-model="testModel" 
        ng-options="labels.indexOf(label) as label for label in labels">
</select>
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwBXBx

Comment: I see. Thank you. Do you by any chance also have any idea why using option with ng-repeat (which does have $index) only seems to bind on first selection change (the second example in my codepen)?

Comment: Because ngRepeat is not even supposed to work with binding models. This is not the same as useing ngOptions. Probably it has something to do with child scopes ngRepeat  creates for every item. You could sort of six it like this `<option ng-repeat="label in labels" value="{{$index}}">{{label}}</option>` but still not recommended.

Comment: Thank you gain, I can see how that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an array of string values, which I want to bind to a select's
>   options and bind the index of the selected value to a variable...
>
> ...neither using ng-options nor regular options with ng-repeat seems to
>   fully work.

ng-options is not working because you are trying to use `$index` with it(which only works with `ng-repeat`). to make your code work with ng-option, you need to replace

```
ng-options="$index as label for label in labels"
```

with

```
ng-options="labels.indexOf(label) as label for label in labels"
```

Secondly, ng-repeat is not working because you are using `$index` on `ng-value` but the value in `ng-model` has no associated index with it.

To make your code work with `ng-repeat`, you may simply use `ng-selected` in `<option>` as follows:

```
  <option  ng-repeat="label in labels" ng-selected = "{{label == testVal}}"  ng-value="$index">
    {{label}}
  </option>
```

Here's the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/06LjLZ3ubnt8JtFaWbWp?p=preview)